# Unable to flash GApps zip after lineage OS 18.1 ROM

Tags: samsung, twrp, lineageos, google-apps

I have flashed a lineage OS 18.1 custom ROM on my Samsung A30 device. I am able to boot into the system successfully. However, I am facing issues while flashing Open Gapps. I have followed below steps:

1. Flashed Lineage OS 18.1 (`lineage-18.1-20220414-UNOFFICIAL-arm64_bvS.img.xz`) using TWRP recovery. (selected `System Image`)
2. Booted into the system.
3. Enabled 'USB Debugging' in developer options.
4. Turned off the device.
5. Booted into Recovery mode (TWRP)
6. Install > Install Zip > OpenGapps.zip
7. Got the error code 70 (insufficient space)
8. Again went back to home screen of TWRP
9. Wipe > Selected 'System' > Advanced Wipe > Resize File System.
10. Got this error - `/sbin/e2fsck -fp /dev/block/mmcblk0p25 process ended with ERROR: 4 Unable to repair system`
11. Tried changing file system of '`System`' to `EXT2` and then back `EXT4`. [I am little bit skeptical of this step, since I feel this would wipe out the entire partition (owing to my experience in installing Arch Linux, where the user should format a file in ext4 partition for `/home`). Nevertheless, I followed this because it was mentioned in of the forums]
12. Boot into system. Now the device is stuck in boot loop.

I am not quite sure, where I am going wrong. I am using TWRP 3.3.1-0.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, flashing Gapps should be done before the first boot. This is mentioned for all devices in [the official LineageOS wiki](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/a5y17lte/install): "***NOTE**: If you want the Google Apps add-on on your device, you must follow this step **before** booting into LineageOS for the first time!*" Also, which OpenGapps flavor did you choose? `/system` partition usually doesn't have enough space, so only `nano` or `pico` is flashable (e.g. https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-treble-lineage-os-17-1-android-10-q-galaxy-a30.4124411/)

Comment: Though, looks like there are actually 2 questions here? (1) how to flash Gapps on LineageOS (the title), and (2) how to get my device unstuck from the boot loop (the body)

Comment: @AndrewT. , I am using pico flavor. And, I even tried flashing Open Gapps immediately after lineage OS installation. It throws same error - less space available. My only question is how to flash Gapps on Lineage OS

Comment: Any catch on this ? I seriously need the GApps on lineage OS

Comment: after installing LineageOS + Open GApps: *'adb pull /tmp/recovery.log'*

Comment: Should I paste this recovery log here ?

Comment: @alecxs You can get the recovery log here : https://pastebin.com/8BR77aNv

Comment: Looks like you're trying NikGApps? From the log: `/system available size: 32912 KB | Total available size: 32912 KB | Gapps Size: 148559 KB` and looks like that's the issue; there's not enough space available anywhere either on `/system` or `/product`. I'm not sure about the solution though, maybe try to resize the partition or reduce the size of the GApps (if possible).

Comment: what's the output of *'cat /proc/partitions'* please?

Answer (score 1):

there is enough size on partition 4800MB just the file system 1907MB is not using half of it. can be fixed with `resize2fs`

```
resize2fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p25 1171875
```

Comment: I tried resizing in TWRP terminal. It resized, but the new size is 63MB, which is still insufficient for the Gapps

Comment: assuming 4k blocks specifying size 1171875 as additional argument will increase to 4800MB